# Make fixed width flexbox items wrap correctly

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap, fixed-width

I can't manage to wrap flex items correctly if they're fixed width in Google Chrome. However, when using percentage-based widths, everything wraps correctly.

How can I make this work with fixed width items?

See example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wajWLz

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid #ddd 1px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flexbox-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  background: #ddd;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  /* Doesn't wrap correctly */
}
.wrapper-second .item {
  width: 33.333333%
  /* Wraps correctly */
}
```

```html
<p>The wrapper is 300px wide, each item is <strong>100px</strong> wide</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<p>you should see 3 items per row,
  <br />Chrome however wraps after the 2nd item (wraps too soon).</p>

<p>when you change the item width to <strong>33.333333%</strong>, it however wraps correctly.</p>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-second">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<p><strong>Question:</strong> how can I make flexbox wrap fixed width items correctly?</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you have set all elements to `box-sizing: border-box;`. This means that the `width` of `.wrapper` will include the border width.

To fix either:

- Add `box-sizing: content-box;` to `.wrapper`
- Change `width: 300px;` to `width: 302px;` on `.wrapper`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid #ddd 1px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flexbox-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  background: #ddd;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  /* Doesn't wrap correctly */
}
.wrapper-second .item {
  width: 33.333333%
  /* Wraps correctly */
}
```

```html
<p>The wrapper is 300px wide, each item is <strong>100px</strong> wide</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<p>you should see 3 items per row,
  <br />Chrome however wraps after the 2nd item (wraps too soon).</p>

<p>when you change the item width to <strong>33.333333%</strong>, it however wraps correctly.</p>

<div class="wrapper wrapper-second">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

<p><strong>Question:</strong> how can I make flexbox wrap fixed width items correctly?</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with the `border-box` statement.

If you remove it from the universal selector and apply it specifically to the children it seems to work.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid #ddd 1px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -moz-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flexbox-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.item {
  background: #ddd;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 100px;



}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```